# Animate camera location/pitch in mapdeck

Tags: mapdeck

This seems like a simple thing, but I'm stuck. I've been trying to animate the camera angle on a map and export the animation into some sort gif, mp4, etc. On the github website for mapdeck (https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/layers.html) some of the vignettes show this kind of zoom/pitch/camera location animation -- but the code provided for the vignettes (https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/blob/master/vignettes/layers.Rmd) only produces still images.

Would anyone be able to provide code that would create the kind of animation shown for "Grid" in the vignettes on the github site (https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/layers.html) as an example?

Thank you in advance!

(I've tried using mapdeck_view with a "duration" and "transition" argument with no success yet.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the animations on the website are screen recordings of manually panning / tiltinig the map.